# Juntar tablas en Andorid-Studio, one2one y many2many

Tags: sql, android-studio, base-de-datos

estoy realizando un trabajo de Android-Studio en el que se me demanda juntar 3 tablas.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDatos){

        BaseDatos.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USUARIOS(Nombre String primary key, Apellidos String, Contrasenya String);");
        BaseDatos.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS(Nombre String primary Key, Cantidad String , Imagen String);");
        BaseDatos.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS_SELECCION(Nombre String primary Key, Imagen String);");}
```

Por el momento esta es la base de la que dispongo, lo que he de conseguir es juntar:

-one2one --> PRODUCTOS y PRODUCTOS_SELECCION, de tal forma que un producto solo pueda tener un producto_seleccion y viceversa

-many2many --> USUARIOS y PRODUCTOS, de tal forma que todos puedan tener los que quiere

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Comment: one2one = uno a uno , many2many = muchos a muchos, por si acaso da a confusión, lo siento

Comment: He conseguido crear el N:N pero me lo tumba, dice que esta mal

Comment: BaseDatos.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USUARIOS_PRODUCTOS_REL(Usuario String PRIMARY KEY, Producto String PRIMARY KEY," +
                " FOREIGN KEY(Usuario) REFERENCES Usuario(Nombre), FOREIGN KEY(Producto) REFERENCES Producto(Nombre))");